# Can a triphase current regulator be used with just two phases?

Tags: three-phase, single-phase

My house is located somewhere with power problems, these have been going on for 15 years and will probably never be fixed. Family lives next door and I want to regulate the power to both my house and theirs with a pure sinus wave power regulator. I was thinking of getting a 15kva/9000W triphase 380V and only use two phases, one for my house and one for theirs.

Our power lines run on 220V. Would this work?! Or do I need to get two single phase 15kva/9000w 220V units.

[BRAUN GROUP ES-SVC 15KVA](http://www.mondoplast.ro/download/6643/ES-SVCSeries380V.pdf)

Unit spec:
BRAUN GROUP ES-SVC 15KVA , Triphase

Main Features:

- Three phase compensation servo motor technology
- Wide AC input voltage range 276-450V
- **100% unbalanced loading capability between three phases**
- Digital display for voltage and current
- Isolated manual bypass switch
- Full protections such as over voltage, under voltage, overload, overheat, etc
- Selectable 6s/180s output delay
- Optional surge/spike protection (replaceable SPD)
- Optional output isolation transformer
- Optional RS232/RS485  Typical Applications:
- Multi-color printing machines
- Air compressors
- CNC machines
- Punching machines
- Laser cutting machines
- Welding machines
      Specifications:

INPUT
Rated Input Voltage
380V (400V/415V Optional)
InputVoltageRange
276-450V
Input Frequency
45-65Hz
Power Factor
0.98

OUTPUT
Rated Output Voltage
380V (400V/415V Optional)
Output Precision
±3% (±1% Optional)
Response Time
<1s, against 10% variation of input voltage
Efficiency
over 96%

DIGITAL DISPLAY
Input Voltage
Line Voltage: AB, BC, CA          Phase Voltage: A, B, C
Output Voltage
Line Voltage: AB, BC, CA          Phase Voltage: A, B, C
Output Current
Phase Current: A, B, C

PROTECTION
Output Under Voltage
Output cutoff by contactor + "L" in display + Buzzer beeping
Output Over Voltage
Output cutoff by contactor + "H" in display + Buzzer beeping
Overload
Output cutoff by contactor + "F" in display + Buzzer beeping
Overheat
Output cutoff by contactor + "C" in display + Buzzer beeping
Phase Failure
Output cutoff by contactor + Buzzer beeping
Wrong Phase Sequence
Can't switch on regulator
Short Circuit
Input cutoff by air breaker
Bypass
Isolated Manual Bypass Switch (Automatic Bypass Optional)
Output Delay Time
6s/180s Selectable
Surge Spike Optional
Replaceable SPD
RS232/RS485 Optional

SAFETY
Insulation Voltage  2,000V / 60s
Insulation Resistance   >5MΩ
Creepage Distance   >8mm
Grounding Resistance    <0.1mΩ
Insulation Class of Coil    Class F (155?)
Cooling Mode    Cooling Fan
IP Level    IP20
Audible Noise

OPERATING CONDITIONS
Operating Temperature   -5°C - +45°C
Operating Humidity  10%-90%, non-condesing
Operating Altitude  <1,000m

MODEL AVAILABLE:
Model No.
15KVA
Capacity
15kVA/9kW
Machine Size
D600 x W520 x H1080 mm
N.W.
78kgs
Packing Size
D610 x W530 x H1200 mm
G.W.
88kgs

Comment: Two single phase inverters should be cheaper due to higher utilization.

Comment: It is the other way around, one unit single phase, everyone needs one, cost is 100$ less than a three phase unit. So two single phase units would cost me almost double.

Comment: I don’t know the prices. What I know is passing only two phases of a three phase inverter is 67 % utilization while you paid for 100 %.

Comment: Yes but it is 40% cheaper than two single phase units, and I get one phase free for future who knows...

Comment: Then you just need to read the manual and/or ask the manufacturer. In theory there should be no problem but in reality there might be a protection kicking in.

Comment: Is the unit single-phase in or three-phase in? You should also consider just supplying regulated power to the devices that actually need it.

Comment: @winny added some specs from the unit, it even says it supports 100% unbalanced load on each phase.

Comment: @Transistor it is three phase in, added unit spec for more info. Supplying separate devices is cumbersome, i need at least 3-4 small units to cover the central heating, microwave, air consitioning. In winter voltage drop as low as 182V from 220V and the microwave, for example, takes 30 min to heat something that would have taken 5 min. It just falls out of spec and barely turns on.

Comment: Just complain with the utility company? Install a tap changing transformer to compensate?

Comment: And are you intending to power it from 3-phase or single-phase?

Comment: @Transistor goind to power it from two single phases, the third phase will remain unused. Output will be two single phases one goes to my house one to family's.

Comment: @winny Don't know what that is... do you have a model recommendation? Does it need manual adjustment or it compensates automatically?

Comment: Google it. Product recommendations are off topic here. Automatically.

Comment: @unmircea: Have you got 2-phases (of a 3-phase grid) and neutral coming into your house? That would be very strange. If you are thinking of taking a phase from each house I would think you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons you haven't explained, you seem to have access to two-phases of a three-phase supply. If you power the inverter from this you are effectively running on one phase. One likely problem is that the internal DC bus will probably not hold up well with single-phase supply.

[image]

*Figure 1. Three-phase recitification provides low-ripple DC without any smoothing capacitors. Source: [if a standard three-phase 400V AC connection is rectified what DC voltage comes out of it?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/if-a-standard-three-phase-400v-ac-connection-is-rectified-what-dc-voltage-comes)*

The single-phase varieties will have large smoothing capacitors built in to hold the DC bus voltage up during the zero-cross.

If you're thinking of adding capacitors to the three-phase unit then you need to be aware that the built-in surge protection to limit the capacitor initial charge current (they look like short-circuits when completely discharged) may be significantly different.

Comment: a 3-phase inverter does not typically have a neutral connection, necessary for single-phase applications.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a triphase current regulator be used with just two phases?

You mean with only two phases loaded on the output? Sure, but if you need to extract the full available power, there may be problems.

> 100% unbalanced loading capability between three phases

It seems that this particular regulator can shift power between the phases.

But in case it didn't, you'd use a so-called [Scott-T transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott-T_transformer) arrangement to convert 3 phases into 2 phases, with the load from two phases distributed onto three incoming phases.