# Power-supply input power problem; single phase 220 V AC need to connect to 3-phase multi-voltage (208~520 V AC)

Tags: power-supply, power, three-phase, input, single-phase

I bought POWER SUPPLY 3-PHASE, SMOOTHED.

I used previous power supply 1-phase as following condition;

1. Previous supply spec.: 960W 24V 40A
2. Input: 1 phase 2 wire
3. Output: 24V DC / around 20A
4. Load: Signal power (PLC, panel fault lamp, LOP switch, LOP touch screen power, encoder power, relay power)

Question No.1

- Is possible to use input power (1 phase 2 wire) instead of 3-phase?

Question No.2

- If No.1 question possible, how to connect wire?

Question No.3

- If use 1 phase instead of 3-phase, which problems happen? ( ex) power drop, safety problems etc.)

Question No.4

- If 1 phase-2 wire can't connect directly, is there other way can possible?
  like using device before power supply input.

Please answer asap.

Thanks.

Comment: The handbook for your PSU should answer these questions.

Comment: JSY - Hi, Questions about how to use a particular product should be addressed to that product's manufacturer or support agents etc. Thanks.

Comment: JSY - I see that you have now removed the manufacturer and model of your power supply from your question, to try to change this from being classed as a "usage question" (which caused its initial closure). I don't believe that removing those details helps readers here, as your questions 1-3 relate to the behavior of *that* power supply - whose identification you removed. You have not added any details of what information the PS manufacturer gave you, when you contacted them. However I will re-open the question, in case the community wants to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Three-phase rectifier and resultant waveform. Image source: [Unattributed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/198617/73158).*

The power supply you are describing probably uses small smoothing capacitors - if any - because it doesn't need them when running on three phases. The resultant DC from the three-phase bridge never drops to zero and the ripple voltage would be quite acceptable for many industrial applications.

Running the power supply on single phase would present the following problems:

1. The primary single-phase would have to be fed at the required phase-phase voltage.
2. The diodes would be stressed as the current is spread over fewer components.
3. The output would have much higher ripple - possibly very close to half-wave rectified waveform.
4. It's designed for three-phase, not single.

This answer is based on the PSU being [Murr 85957](http://se-import.com/documents/catalog/powering/murr/transformers/85957.pdf) as listed in the original version of your question.